# Proving convergence in probability of discrete variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

I'm working with the following sequence of independent random variables:

$$X_1 \equiv 0$$
and for $n \geq 2$:
$$
P(X_n = j) =\begin{cases}
  \frac{1}{n^3}&j = \pm1, \pm2, ..., \pm n\\
  1-\frac{2}{n^2}&j=0
\end{cases}
$$

And trying to prove the average converges in probability to $0$:
$$
S_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{X_i}{n} \xrightarrow{P} 0
$$

My main issue is I don't exactly know how to work with $S_n$, not about the convergence itself. By definition of convergence in probability, I'm trying to prove $P(|S_n| > \varepsilon ) \xrightarrow{} 0$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$. I tried finding the pmf of $S_n$ by using the convolution operator for distributions, but has gotten me no where.

Any tips/hints on how to work with $S_n$ will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens as you take $n$ to infinity, based on the definition of $P(X_n = j)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $|S_n| \le \frac{1}{n} \sum_j{ |X_j|} $. But $E(|X_j|) = \frac{1+j}{j^2} \le \frac{2}{j}$, so $E(|S_n|) \le \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n{ \frac{2}{j}} = 2\frac{ln(n)}{n}(1+o) \rightarrow 0$. Apply Markov's inequality to the result.

Comment: How does one derive the last equality, of the finite sum? I can't seem to find it online

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics